# when saving the entity , I get Attempting to save one or more entities that have a non-nullable association with an unsaved transient entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Java 17 Spring + Hibernate

There are two entities

```
@Entity
public class Quest {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    private Country country;

}
    
@Entity
public class Country {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;
}
```

I save entities separately in order to perform checks on the Country entity before that and possibly change the Quest entity.
Here is the class of the service in which the entities are saved.
I save the Country entity first so that the corresponding entry has already been created in the country table.

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class QuestServiceImpl implements QuestService {

    private final QuestRepository questRepository;

    private final CountryService countryService;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Quest save(Quest quest) {
    
        var country = quest.getCountry().getName();
        // Checks are performed here before saving
        countryService.save(getCountry(country));
        return questRepository.save(quest);
    }

    Country getCountry(String name) {
     ...
        return country;
    }
}

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CountryServiceImpl implements CountryService {

    private final CountryRepository countryRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Country save(Country country) {
        return countryRepository.save(country);
    }

}
```

As a result, I get an error

```
HHH000437: Attempting to save one or more entities that have a non-nullable association with an unsaved transient entity. The unsaved transient entity must be saved in an operation prior to saving these dependent entities.
```

I understand that the problem is that all the code is executed within a single transaction.
But my CountryServiceImpl#save method is also marked as @Transactional.
How do I fix this?

If I remove @Transactional in CountryServiceImpl, I still get the same error. But in this case, the data is written to the Country table. But they are still not written to the Quest table. The same thing happens if I remove @Transactional in both services.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `@Transactional` in `CountryServiceImpl`. Since the QuestServiceImpl class has `@Transactional` on the save() method, the method will execute within a single transaction, including the `countryService.save()` invoke.

Comment: It didn't help. I added a description of this to the question.